# Windows Server 2008 R2 - How do I move my System Volume to a new SSD?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a system volume in Windows Server 2008 R2 that I have shrunk to well under the size of a 40 GB SSD.

What steps should I perform to move the image to the SSD and boot from it instead?

The only complication is that the source HDD has three volumes, one that is a few MB reserved by windows, one that is about 35 GB, and one that is about 500 GB (Data volume). Clearly I only want the first two volumes on the SSD, thus, I suspect I may need to use some built in windows 2008 functionality to get them operating correctly on the new drive.

Moving the data volume to another drive to simplify matters is a possibility...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy!  Purchase (or use a free) [disk imaging/cloning tool](http://www.clonehdd.com/).

- Install that software on another machine
- Shut down your server, and remove the HDD
- Shutdown the other machine, and insert both HDDs (the server disk, and the SSD)
- Clone
- Shutdown the other machine and put the SSD drive into the server

Comment: Updated the question to show a complication -- I have a large data volume on the source HDD... so imaging isn't possible (since it's 1 TB --> 40 GB). Thanks

Comment: You only copy the partitions that you want.  This is trivial with something like Norton Ghost or Partition Manager.  Just make sure that whatever one you use is compatible with Server 2008